# Opel Vectra 1.9CDTI 2008 caravan, clutch making a strange noise

Tags: clutch, opel, vectra

I have a Opel Vectra 2008 1.9CDTI caravan. It has 177 000 kilometers behind. I got the gearbox changed to a refitted M32 at local garage. Before the gearbox was changed i got the clutch and DMF replaced at the same garage. The original gearbox failed after 50 kilometers of driving with the new clutch installed.

Before and after all these fixes i can hear strange buzzing/humming/rattling noise coming from the engine compartment. The noise does not sound that bad and you really need to focus to hear it.

The noise will appear when i press the clutch all the day down. Giving the engine some revs will stop the noise, but right after the revs come down to normal idling level the noise comes back.

Engine temperature does not seem to affect the noise.

EDIT: Yesterday (2.5.2018) i visited the local garage where the clutch and gearbox services were made. The mechanic located the sound and said it is most likely coming from the water pump or the high pressure pump and it is nothing to worry about, as i have warranty for all the new parts plus the whole car itself. He also said it should be common for a revised gearbox to make some noise. I'm going to take the car to a certified Opel mechanic just to see what they think and to be sure.

Comment: Those M32 gearboxes have a reputation for throwing bearings, i assume that is why the original was replaced? Is the 'new' gearbox a revised model or just another one that still worked?
The noise is most likely not from the clutch but from the input shaft of the gearbox.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the M32 gearbox is a revised one by Hellsten. It costed around 2300 euros. The reason behind replacing the original was the bearings. At the end the bearings were so worn that some parts of the gearbox flew out trough the box casing, near where the bearings are located, creating a small hole in to the casing of the box.

Comment: While I won't comment on the source of the noise I will comment on the opinion of the mechanic: A gearbox is either silent or defect. An noisy bearing won't cure itself. Should the sound really come from the gearbox it needs to be serviced.

Comment: I will try to capture the noise in a video and upload it tomorrow if i have time. Thanks for the replies.